# VBA / Visio: Open SaveAs Dialog with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, visio

I want to open a save as dialog for the user via VBA. I found this method:

```
   Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ("c:\my_folder\")
```

from this previous question [save as dialog excel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522278/save-as-dialog-excel-code)

Obviously, it does not work in Visio. What is the corresponding Argument for Visio?  Cant seem to find a list of all possible options online.

Another possibility I found is

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

but that does not work in Visio either!

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You should be able to find plenty of examples online with a simple Google search. 'se the SaveAs method to save a document for the first time.    `ThisDocument.SaveAs "path\filename.vsd" ` or `Me.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(docPath)` or save as new path `Me.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAsEx(newDocPath`

Comment: Thanks for the input! I cant test your code immediately but I think this lets me save the file to a given path. I want however, the User to be able to choose the file! Just as if one clicked the "Save as" button. Sorry if I wasnt clear above.

Comment: Not an answer as such, but you can search in the Object Browser (that little box with the shapes coming out from it on the VBA editor tool bar)  for "SaveAs".

Comment: Ahh - okay - yes if you want to use the Win API method you can use Ken Getz's plug and play module from http://access.mvps.org/Access/api/api0001.htm  and just call it  like`strSaveFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( OpenFile:=False, Filter:=strFilter, Flags:=ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT Or ahtOFN_READONLY)`

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762039/open-a-filedialog-in-visio-vba. Voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Visio VBA object model haven't own build-in dialog box collection for save documents.
You can add MS Excel library in references of your VBA-project. 
Tools -> References
[image] 
Press button **Browse** and find MS Excel library
[image]
Look also this list [XlBuiltInDialog Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlbuiltindialog-enumeration-excel)